# Questions on entanglement entropy

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, quantum-entanglement, ads-cft, entanglement-entropy

- If the spatial entangling surface is $M$ then it seems that one way to get the entanglement entropy is to think of the QFT on the manifold $S \times M$ where $S$ is a 2-manifold with the metric, $ds^2 = d\rho^2 + sin^2\rho d\theta^2$ where $\theta$ has a periodicity, $0 \leq \theta \leq \beta = 2\pi n$. If $F$ is the free energy on this product manifold then it follows that the entanglement entropy is given by $S = [\beta \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} - 1 ](\beta F) \vert _{\beta = 2\pi}$

I would like to know what is the proof of the above and how often does it work? This looks like the branched Riemann surface argument in these papers http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.4013.pdf but this seems vastly more simple! Why?

- Lets say the spatial manifold is a sphere and one wants the entanglement entropy for some CFT across some curve on the sphere. Now one can stereographically project the sphere onto a plane and hope to calculate the entanglement entropy of the CFT on the plane across the stereographic image of the curve on the plane. Will these two be equivalent?

  May be for general QFTs this will not work but for CFTs will it work given that the stereographic projection is locally biholomorphic?

Comment: Note that the relation $S = [\beta \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} - 1 ](\beta F)$, is a standard relation, for a canonical ensemble. It comes easily from the definition of $F= - \frac{1}{\beta} \ln Z$, the definition of the partition function $Z= \sum\limits_i e^{-\beta E_i}$, the  definition of the entropy $S=-\sum\limits_i p_i \ln p_i$, with $p_i = \frac{1}{Z} e^{-\beta E_i}$.

Comment: @Trimok Well - my question was about why F calculated on that conical singularity manifold does the work. This product manifold being used doesn't obviously look the same as the branched Riemann surface being used in the linked paper -right?

Comment: I think the paragraph you quoted is essentially the same as the "branched Riemann surface argument". It is just stated more formally. Also, please link to the abstract page not the pdf file.

Comment: @IsidoreSeville SO you think that the branched Riemann surface that the linked paper draws is indeed such a simple product manifold? If yes, then can you kindly explain why?

Comment: This is just the replica trick. Please see [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4646) for a down-to-earth exposition. You can convince yourself this is indeed correct by considering (1) 1+1D field theory, M being a point and (2) 2+1D field theory in flat space, M being a line.

Comment: I'd like to add that the paper you cited considered a more complicated case, namely multiple disconnected entangling surfaces. This is (usually) necessary if you want to compute the ES in a massless theory. It is easier to start with a massive theory and a single entangling surface.

Comment: @IsidoreSeville So you are saying that if the situation is that of having a single entangling surface then the entanglement entropy can be derived from the calculation of the free-energy on the product of the entangling surface and such a conical 2-manifold? Would you know how finite temperature is included in this?

Comment: Yes, at least when the geometry of entangling surface and the base manifold is simple. Normally people compute the entanglement entropy at zero temperature because it is more interesting (entanglement is not so well defined at finite temperature). You can generalize the replica trick to finite temperature and you end up with one dimension becomes finite.

Comment: @IsidoreSeville How do you see that this product manifold is the same as the branched Riemann surface drawn in the linked paper? Do you have references about calculating entanglement entropy at finite temperatures? (..at 0 temperature the idea is to map EE to thermal entropy on hyperbolic cyclinders or de-Sitter spaces - what happens to these constructions at finite temperature?...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12794/discussion-between-isidore-seville-and-user6818)